# Unity 2D Character Don't Stop Jumping

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Okay so I changed the code and added new c# script. i checked the box coliders they are good. Now the problem is that I cant jump.

This is what I changed in Move2DPlayer

```
private void Jump()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded == true)
        {
          gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f, 5f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
```

This is the new c# its called "Grounded"

```
public class Grounded : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject Player;

    private void Start()
    {
        Player = gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject;

    }


    private void Update()
    {

    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Ground")
        {
            Player.GetComponent<Move2DPlayer>().isGrounded = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Ground")
        {
            Player.GetComponent<Move2DPlayer>().isGrounded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check your collider layers and `whatIsGround`? Is it possible that `Physics2D.OverlapCircle(rb.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);` always returns true because it overlaps with the player collider itself? Because I tested your code without changing anything and it works for me including the extra jumps in the air. After those I can not jump until back on the ground so it has to be your layers

Answer (score 0):

Your player probably has a `Collider2D` itself and either `whatIsGround` is not configured correctly or your player has a wrong layer so

```
Physics2D.OverlapCircle(rb.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);
```

returns always `true` because you collide with the player itself.

I tested your code without any changes and it works for me:

[image]

---

However some performance and other considerations:

- Do not `Debug.Log` in `Update` or `FixedUpdate` .. for development it's fine but make sure to remove it later! It's very performance intense.
- You can set the Inspector to debug mode.

  [image]

  This way you can see the values of private fields and you should notice that `isGrounded` is probably always `true` in your case

  [image]
- Just a beautify thing but instead of `somebool == true` and `somebool == false` rather simply use `somebool` and `!somebool`